# How do I install Android applications from the PC?

Tags: networking, android

Currently I don't have an Internet connection available on my cellphone and I would like to install some applications on it.

Is it possible?
Do I have to use the market?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Android Debug Bridge (adb)](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) to install applications. You need to connect your phone to your computer via USB and possess the `.apk` file to do it. Check out the [Installing an Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move) section on that page.

ADB requires the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html). So you must first install that.

The easier solution though is if your phone has Wi-Fi, just connect to an access-point and then open the Android Market.

Comment: Just FYI the command you use is "adb install <package.apk>"

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the PC.

I actually prefer transferring APK files over to the SD card and then running them from the phone via a file browsing application. You could also use [Android Market from the emulator](http://tech-droid.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-market-on-emulator.html).

But, assuming you have a Wifi connection you could:

- Click on APK files from websites via browser
- Use alternatives to the Market, for example [SAM](http://slideme.org/)

ALso: My HTC Magic came with a crappy ROM with no Google products including Market. So I flashed a Hero port onto my phone. Something worth considering. It's risky business nevertheless.